# Globally validate user input in classic ASP

Tags: validation, vbscript, asp-classic, request-validation

What is <strike>the best</strike> your favorite way of globally validating user input in classic ASP?

I inherited a legacy classic ASP project where I need to validate user input. Currently no validation is done. In ASP.net one can set `<pages validateRequest="true" />` in `web.config` - is there something similar [to this](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/ASP.NET_Request_Validation) in classic ASP?

The only other way I can think of, to validate user input, is by going into each and every page - I hope someone has a more efficient idea :-)

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't answer your first question because it is subjective. :)

There is no equivalent to ASP.NET Request Validation in ASP Classic.  You must build one yourself.

Comment: Rephrased my first question ;-)

Comment: To implement something like this you would have to put code into a globally included script.

Comment: When it comes to protection from XSS, I feel most comfortable using a combination of custom developed scripts to validate untrusted user input, i.e. I have a function that tests `vartype` and one that uses RegEx to strip or encode illegal characters from inputs.  Additionally, I lock down the character set of my application to UTF-8 as much as possible.

Comment: Would you mind sharing some of these custom scripts, e.g. for illegal characters from inputs? :-)

Comment: The following filters out anything tha tmatches an inputted regular expression from the inputting string:  

`public function Filter(strPattern, strTestString)
  dim oRegX
  set oRegX = new RegExp

  with oRegX
   .pattern = strPattern
   .global = true
   .ignorecase = false
   strTestString = .replace(strTestString, "")
  end with

  kill oRegX

  Filter = strTestString
 end function`